# How to reset Material UI Autocomplete to the default value/ initial value on click of reset?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, reset, default-value

I am working on Material UI Autocomplete with react to have a dynamic dropdown list. When i click on the reset button, i want to reset the value in the autocomplete to be set to the default value. I have been looking everywhere for a solution, but have not been able to find one.

Any suggestions / solutions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a changing key on your Autocomplete? This will allow you to recharge only this one.